# Google Charts Timeline: how can I left-justify the row labels

Tags: php, html, css, google-visualization, timeline

I would like to left-justify all the row labels in my Google Charts Timeline. The documentation says "timeline.rowLabelStyle" only supports font type, color, and size, and I have not been able to get the "allowHtml" keyword to work.

I also tried the following, but no luck:

```
.customChartStyle{
    text-align:left !important;
}

...

chart.draw(data, {width: 950, height: 600, 'cssClassNames': {'tableCell': 'customChartStyle'}});
```

If someone can please tell me how I can customize the row labels as desired I'd appreciate it much.

Comment: Changing the alignment of labels is not supported.  You can file a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support.

Answer (score 1):

This works after the fact

```
$('#myTimeline div div div svg g:first text').attr({'x':5,"text-anchor":"start"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it need to import a library for execute the script below?

```
$('#myTimeline div div div svg g:first text').attr({'x':5,"text-anchor":"start"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but I managed to move the timeline row labels to the left doing the following (jQuery way):

```
$('#myTimeline div div div div svg g:first text').attr({'x': 5, 'text-anchor': 'start'});
```